# the cause for using javascript parameter.target

Tags: javascript

i'm really confused about the fs function. i mean i don't understand when i should use the
 **function parameter**,function **parameter.target** and when **this**.For example this code:

```
  e.target.addEventListener('mouseout',function handler(d)
        {   
            var divE=d.target.parentNode.querySelector('div.preview');
            divE.parentNode.removeChild(divE);
            e.target.removeEventListener('mouseout',handler,false);
        },false);
```

why is used e.target and neither e nor this?

Comment: `this` is the element that `addEventListener` was called on.  `e.target` is the (child) element that the event was triggered on.  They may be the same, they may be different.  `e` is an [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#Properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e.target` is typically used when delegating an event handler to an element that has dynamic children or descendants. Using delegation, you need to check `e.target` to find out which descendant element triggered the event, because the event has bubbled up from the descendant.

Delegation ins't just used when you have dynamic elements. It's also useful when for example, you have lots of elements which all need an event handler. In that case you might prefer to delegate to the parent element just once, instead of assigning the event listener to all descendants.

The `this` context is the element that has the event listener assigned, so if you aren't doing delegation then `this` can be used.